# Use portal2 editor on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: portal-2, linux

I have installed portal 2 on Steam as a native application not trough Wine. 
Is it possible to to use the editor trough Steam on Ubuntu 12.04?
Somebody tried?

Found that my graphics card is still not supported by ATI with Linux drivers :D

Some useful links which I will probably not try to follow:

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Saucy_Installation_Guide

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/846938351012409765/#p7

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer-experimental-13

I tried to install proprietary driver for Steam from System Settings -> Additional Drivers. All went well until I restarted. I saw the Ubuntu logo and then black screen.

I fixed this issue by restarting my laptop from the ACPI button and then booting to Ubuntu recovery mode. Enabled networking and then loaded root mode. Typed these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade // this is not necessary but you can upgrade your system t0 latest updates
```

restart

I also downloaded AMD legacy driver from here: http://geeko.ioda.net/mirror/amd-fglrx-legacy/raw-src/

amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run

in terminal I run:

```
sudo amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
```

It will create three deb files. I installed the first one: fglrx_8.970-0ubuntu1_i386.deb

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx_8.970-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

Then restart. And as I can see it works :D I can play Portal on my Ubuntu 12.04.
But ok I see "AMD Unsupported hardware" icon on bottom right of  screen.

Next thing is to install Portal 2 and Editor.

Comment: I cannot get it to run Portal 2. I am having trouble with OpenGL drivers. Tried to remove fglrx and installed the ATI catalyst driver experimental, version 13. Ended up with black screen after boot. Have to check this. I have ASUS laptop Radeon HD 7470M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out yes you can use the editor once you properly install Portal 2. At first you have to manually opt into the beta. Right click game list item, goto properties, goto beta tab, and opt in.

Don't forget to change resolution to 1024x768 afterwards.

Happy editing :D